# Adding Google Maps - Only seeing blank screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to add Google Maps. However, after building the apk from Build > Generate Signed apk and installing it to a real device, the activity only shows a blank screen, with the Google logo in the lower left. Is there something wrong with the following codes?

**Notes**
API Key is in both google_maps_api.xml and strings.xml, and API Key in below code is not shown

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1">

<permission
    android:name="com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1.MapsActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Gradle (Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
}
```

**Gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/' }
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1.MapsActivity"));
        }
    });
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
package com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng Angeles = new LatLng(15.1427956, 120.5977875);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Angeles).title("Marker in Angeles"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Angeles));
}
}
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.thesis.cutaneous.testapp1.MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: If there is a blank screen, I somewhat doubt Android Studio is the problem. You simply write the code there. Once the code compiles, it's outside of the IDE's control

Comment: Where can I access it? I'm only using a device that is not connected to a PC when the app is run.

Comment: If the google logo is displayed with the no map, then most probably it would be an issue with the API key. Are yu sure that you used a new API key with the signed key?

Comment: I see. Please clarify. I'm still unfamiliar with these terms and procedures.

Comment: I would second the issue is most likely with your API key. Are you aware that you need different keys for Debug and production builds? If your app runs when you run it without going through the *Generate Signed APK* route but not when you do, then chances are you haven't set up a release key correctly.

Comment: I am not aware of the things you mentioned. How should I fix this then?

Comment: Best to try the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) first, which outlines how to generate a debug and release api key. You store them under `src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` for the debug key and `src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` for release. [Here](https://github.com/PPartisan/FantasyMapTutorial/tree/master/app/src) is as an example project I made using the map API with this structure.

Comment: Thanks @PPartisan. I'm currently trying how to understand how the process works. Thanks for the sample project as well.

Answer (score 0):

Blank map is caused by incorrect google_maps_key. Note that there are 2 different keys - one for debug, one for release build. You have to register both on  https://console.developers.google.com/. To determine your release key run something like this in your project directory:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin"\keytool  -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

Comment: This one is really bad explained but gave me the hint. I have my Google maps API restricted to my app. When building a signed apk, you must register the SHA1 from the keystore by running the command described in this answer (you have to cd to the file's location). Then you save the SHA1 in the console for the restricted item